# Access a Windows ODBC System DSN from a linux machine (Apache)

Tags: apache, odbc, dsn

Currently our web server (Windows XAMP) has access to our (AccountEdge ODBC) as its on the same machine and user account.
I have setup a Linux vm with a LAMP stack. Everything on the web/sql/php front is working well.
Is it even possible to connect to a Win ODBC from another machine.
The AccountEdge ODBC does not have any remote support built in on the ODBC.

Current connection string:

```
$db_myob = odbc_connect('MYOB','','');
```

Tried and failed string:

```
$db_myob = odbc_connect('DRIVER={MYOCA2202};Server=192.168.55.20;Database=MYOB', '', '');
```